# Can I have an overlapping Schengen (Visa C) and a Swiss Visa 'D'?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, france, switzerland

a bit of background information: 
my passport does not allow me visa free access to europe nor Schengen so I would need a Visa.

I will be going for around 6 months of exchange in Switzerland - which means a visa 'D'. However, I have no intention of going early so I may go in late February.

The thing is, in (early) January, I am intending to travel to UK and France/Netherlands with some other friends. Obviously I would need a UK Visa. However, regarding the France, would I (or more specifically, Can i ) apply for a Schengen Visa ? Because the validity would overlap into the start of the Swiss Visa 'D'.

-> Because aside from that, I guess the other way is to request for the Swiss Visa 'D' to start earlier (i.e. to start on the day i intend to travel to France).

I'll be requesting a multiple entry visa of course because after the UK/France travel, I will come back to Singapore (i'm not a Singapore passport holder) to stay for another 3 - 4 weeks before I leave for Switzerland.

Tl;dr 
If I have a Swiss Visa 'D' that starts in say end-Feb, can i apply for a French schengen visa C for early Jan ?

Or can I request for my Swiss Visa 'D' to start in early Jan but I do not enter Switzerland (i.e. use it for my travel to France then back to Singapore, before travelling again to Switzerland come end Feb)

I am not sure if the latter is allowed though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If everybody is careful, a C visa could be granted until the day before your D visa starts. At midnight, you stop staying on the C visa and start staying on the D visa.

- A D visa can be used to travel in the Schengen area like a C visa. The 90/180-day rule will apply for any combination of visa, **except** for days in the nation that issued the D.
- If there is an overlap, no harm done.
- Making your D application more complex by tacking on tourism could increase the likelihood that it will be denied.
- Getting a C visa *may* be easier if you already have a D visa for a later date.

Answer (score 4):

Just thought I'd follow up with an update as an answer.

So I finally have settled all the visa stuff. There is an overlap for my case.

I applied for a Schengen 'C' Visa double entry for an 8 days trip - and was given a multiple entry, 6 month validity visa. I asked the consular officers at the embassy if the overlap was an issue & they said it's not seeing that they are 2 different visa types (though the 'D' Visa has been given parity of movement in Schengen).

Anyway yep hope it helps others who might have the same query!