# Swiss Schengen visa - Cancel short stay business visa and get short stay work permit visa

Tags: schengen, switzerland, work, business-travel

I have a work authorization for Switzerland valid until 19th April 2018 for 4 months max.

I intended to get a short-stay work visa for 120 days (Type  D visa) but due to an incorrect appointment at VFS, I received a short-stay business visa (Type C) for 90 days only, even though I had sent my work authorization letter with the application.

I want to know how I can cancel this business visa and how I can get the work visa for 120 days since I have a valid Swiss work authorization letter and I have not yet travelled.

Please help.
Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: 120 days is not "short stay" in the Schengen terminology.

Comment: Ok. But i have work authorization letter for it. So is it possible to get the work permit visa dor 120 days now

Comment: Visa form for Type C and Type D visas are different. Are you sure you filled the correct form?

Comment: Is it possible now to get the Type D visa by taking new apointment and new form? And get this Type C visa cancelled ?

Comment: Yes you are right. Its because my company provided me type C form instead of type D form. But the question is can I now get type C visa cancelled and refill type D form since I have valid work authorization letter for 4 months

Comment: Per [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77711/can-i-have-an-overlapping-schengen-visa-c-and-a-swiss-visa-d) type C and type D visas are regarded as distinct visas and can overlap so possibly you don't need to cancel the existing visa. However as the same consulate will process your type D visa application they may refuse your application and cancel existing visa. I can only recommend contacting swiss visa section by mail and owning up to your mistake of filling the wrong form. They will know what to do (will probably  involve fresh type d application with new fee)

Comment: Thank you guys. I will take this further with the consulate. Any further suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Just an update if in case anyone is interested. I had sent an email to the Swiss Embassy and they replied that - It was an error on their end and they requested me to resubmit my passport, work authorization letter and email copy. And they said they will rectify it.

Comment: @sameer59 I suggest you post this as an answer to help any future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had sent an email to the Swiss Embassy and they replied that - It was an error on their end and they requested me to resubmit my passport, work authorization letter and email copy. And they said they will rectify it.